# Android Studio - Minimizing Duplicate Code - Custom Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a custom toolbar for my application that is included in every activity .xml file except my login page.

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

The custom toolbar has 6 buttons on it. Now, in every class I am having to obtain references to each button as well as create click listeners. I feel like there has to be some solution to minimize my coding here but can't really think of anything off the top of my head and was hoping for assistance.

I was thinking of creating a custom class where I would allow for context in the constructor. The only issue I have with this is that I may find the need to adjust the code for a button click. Maybe there is a way to override a button onClick method and write a new one?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` or `BaseFragment` which will handle the events. if you need to different stuff depending on Component then just provide a call by an abstract method to child component.